# How to calculate conditional expectation of two random variables

Tags: self-study, expected-value, conditional-expectation

[image]

How do I calculate E{Y|Z}? I know I have to consider the case for Z = 1 and Z = 0 but im not sure how to formulate the conditional pdf then make the calculation. What are the bounds the the expectation integral, is it [0, 1] or [0, b]??

[image]

Comment: First, please add the `self-study` tag. Second, tell us more on where you get stuck.  Deriving the conditional expectation implies finding (a) the joint distribution of $(X,Y,Z)$; (b) the joint distribution of $(Y,Z)$; (c) the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditional on $Z$. Where do you get stuck in these steps? An alternative is to see $$Y=\mathbb I_{(0,b)}(X)\qquad Z=\mathbb I_{(a,1)}(X)$$as deterministic functions of $X$ and compute the probability of one event given the other.

Comment: Forget conditional pdf. You have $E[Y\mid Z=1]=E[Y\mid a<X<1]=\frac1{P(a<X<1)}E[YI_{a<X<1}]$. Writing $Y$ as an indicator $I_{0<X<b}$ simplify the numerator. You only need the pdf of $X$ for the calculation.